# Find all duplicates in a column and return all of the same with an offset to left in the same cell

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I want to search column `I` in `"sheet_02"` for duplicated cells and if some are found I want to return for every cell match the cell -7 columns left. All of the same duplicates with the same matching cell value in one cell and for the next matches the next cell below.

To clarify here my example:

Source: `"sheet_02"`

```
<cell B1> name_01    <cell I1> item_01
<cell B2> name_02    <cell I2> item_02
<cell B3> name_03    <cell I3> item_01
<cell B4> name_04    <cell I4> Item_03
<cell B5> name_05    <cell I5> item_01
<cell B6> name_06    <cell I6> item_03
```

The result I'm looking for: `"sheet_01"`

```
<cell A1> name_01
          name_03
          name_05

<cell A2> name_02

<cell A3> name_04
          name_06
```

An example with hard drives of the source: to clarify in my sheet the values representing "item_01" in my question are random strings but some with the same name. And the same for "names_01". So in my sheets where I want to use that code, it looks like my example below. Also, my list of values is much longer.

Hopefully, this example of hard drives makes it clearer. This is still the same pattern.

Source: `"sheet_02"`

```
<cell B1> "Datalibary (30.0GB)"           <cell I1>  "Seagate Barracuda"
<cell B2> "Pictures (10.5GB)"             <cell I2> "Western Digital"
<cell B3> "Movies (100.30GB)"             <cell I3> "Seagate Barracuda"
<cell B4> "Textdocuments (04.GB)"         <cell I4> "Lacie"
<cell B5> "Software (230.10GB)"           <cell I5> "Seagate Barracuda"
<cell B6> "Notes"                         <cell I6> "Lacie"
```

But I'm struggling.

I know I need to use something like that. But that's only the beginning. I'm stuck by trying to return the duplicates with an offset of -7. VLOOKUP won't work as it only returns one value. And I need all duplicates to be grouped and the offset on top of it.

```
=join(char(10), sort(sheet_02!I1:I6))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Excel:
  I turned your data into a Table so I could use Structured References.  But you could use regular references if you need to.

Formula:

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,FILTER(myTbl[Column1], myTbl[Column8]= INDEX(UNIQUE(myTbl[Column8]),ROWS($1:1)))),"")
```

and fill down until you start to see blanks:

**Results with your original data:**

[image]

**With your second set of data:**

[image]

---

**Note**

For Google Sheets, the equivalent formula, as translated from Excel to Sheets by Google, could be:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,FILTER(Sheet_02!$B$1:$B$6, Sheet_02!$I$1:$I$6= INDEX(UNIQUE(Sheet_02!$I$1:$I$6),ROWS($1:1)))),"")), 1, 1)
```

But this seems to work just as well:

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,FILTER(Sheet_02!$B$1:$B$6, Sheet_02!$I$1:$I$6= INDEX(UNIQUE(Sheet_02!$I$1:$I$6),ROWS($1:1)))),"")
```

Comment: I guess `"Column1" ` is a named range for the `"names"` and  `"Column8"` is a named range for  `"items" `?

Comment: @BenjaminK Exactly.  With a Table, columns need to have headers.  I will post a Sheets formula momentarily.

Comment: @BenjaminK If you create a table, the naming will be automatic.  If you already have column headers, the process can use those; if you don't it will create them.  You don't have to "Name" each column manually.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld you create an amazing formula, I also could learn from it. Thank you, even not my own question. haha

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Your G-Sheet formula is currently only returning one hard drive with files in one cell and not as in your screenshot the other hard drives.

Comment: @BenjaminK Did you "fill down" the formula to all of the relevant cells?  Are you using the proper address referncing methods?  It seems to work as required on my copy of Sheets.  see [my example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10qYCMgF2B2XbTue8ex5XP1prSidyqqVrE0-Dlp0qTAs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @BenjaminK I just noticed on my Sheets example that the first row of data was not visible since the interior color was black.  I have changed that.

Comment: @zummon  Thanks. I created the formula in Excel, and then just uploaded the file to Sheets. Google did the conversion of the Excel formula to Sheets (although I did have to make a few edits).

Comment: Your solution is amazing. Simple and clear syntax! Thanks a lot for your effort. I'm still having a question about your formula. Is `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN`and `ARRAYFORMULA` necessary and how does it help. Cause it seems to run even without it.

Comment: @BenjaminK It seems you are correct and I have edited my answer to reflect that.  For the original Sheets formula, I merely uploaded by Excel to Sheets and accepted the translation. I'm not a regular Sheets user.  And I see that it does produce the same results without the `ARRAY_` formula entries.  I suspect the translation has to do with how Excel behaved before Excel had Dynamic Arrays, from when array formulas need to be entered with `ctrl+shift+enter`.

Answer (score 0):

For Google Sheets

Let put more `FILTER()` in `sort()` and use Column B to get the unique value

"B1" put `=UNIQUE(sheet_02!I$1:I$16)`

"A1:..." put `=join(char(10), sort(FILTER(sheet_02!B$1:B$16,sheet_02!I$1:I$16=B1)))`

I hope it'll work for you,

Comment: Thank you a lot for your thoughts on that. I'm sorry but it won't work for my sheet as `item_01` and the others are only synonyms for names to make the question clearer so `item_01` could also be`"Seagate Barracuda (Unity)"` or any other str value.

Comment: Oh that is the way it should be. This way is better, but need to use "B1" to fill more array formula. I updated the answer. If you need column B to use another thing let ask me more for other solutions which not to use column B